# <a href=""> root of folder rather than index.html

Tags: html

I have tried googling but all of the links I find are about linking resources, for example images with `../`, Might be an easy question to solve - but internet searches aren't helpful...

Say I have the folder "html" of which my webserver would use as the root, within that folder is index.html, page.html and page2.html, when linking something I'd usually do: `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` but is there a way to link the root, so you get `demos/` rather than `demos/index.html`.

Comment: Have you tried `href="/"`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, it sends it back to the root folder, not the root of the webserver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`./` is the notation for the root of the current folder

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<a href="../abc.html">Back to Fruits List</a>
```

.. Goes to root ,and you can fetch any page after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the "default" page (such as index.html) on you webserver configuration to see the contents of the directory, but this will expose you site structure which is not a good idea for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Apache HTTP server** you can create a file called **.htaccess** in the **demos** folder (**/demos/.htaccess**) and write the following in it.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

That way when you visit http://example.com/demos/ it will show the index.html